# Forward WSGI cookies to Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies, saml, wsgi

I am developing a WSGI middleware application (Python 2.7) using Werkzeug. This app works within a SAML SSO environment and needs a SAML token to be accessed.

The middleware also performs requests to other applications in the same SAML environment, acting on behalf of the logged in user. In order to do that without the need of user feedback, I need to forward the SAML session cookie that I can get from the WSGI environment to requests that I am performing using the Requests library.

My issue is that the cookies that I get from WSGI/Werkzeug can only be parsed as http.cookies.SimpleCooke , while Requests accepts cookielib.CookieJar instances.

I have not found a way to cleanly forward these session cookies without resorting to shameful hacks such as parsing the raw content of the set-cookie headers.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

gm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are just [HTTP headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1). Just use pull the cookie value from http.cookies.SimpleCookie, and add it to your requests session's cookie [jar](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/cookies/).

Not a hack. :)

Comment: But the cookie value I get from WSGI is a string of key-value pairs separated by colons and equal signs, while all the methods that the requests CookieJar class offers to set cookies only accept dicts and CookieJars. I could definitely use `split()` to get a dict from a string, but it seems a bit clunky and not too reliable, and I wonder if there were a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: OK, I guess this was the cleanest way:


        ```request = Request(environ)
        req_cookies = SimpleCookie(request.cookies)
        req_cookiedict = {
            morsel.key : morsel.value for morsel in req_cookies.values()
        }```

Then I can just add the dict to the `cookies` parameters of the request.